# Using an AngularJS Filter in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning about filters in AngularJS. Currently, I have the following in a controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [
    { id:1, name:'Bill' },
    { id:2, name:'George' },
    { id:3, name:'Jerry' },
    { id:4, name:'Elaine' },
    { id:5, name:'Kramer' }
  ];
}]);
```

I am trying to display all of the people whose name contains 'i'.  I know how to display the names. I just don't know how to filter them. Currently, I'm displaying them using the following:

```
<div ng-controller='MyController'>
  <div>
    People with names that have an "i":
    <span ng-repeat="person in people">({{person.id}}) - {{person.name}} </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I add a filter in the markup such that only those people whose name contains an 'i' appears?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work, you can specify the property where you want the filter to be applied

```
<span ng-repeat="person in people | filter:{ name: 'i' }">
  ({{person.id}}) - {{person.name}})  
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
<span ng-repeat="person in people | filter:'i'">{{person.name}} </span>
```

@source https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: What if I need to show both the person's name and their ID? How does the filter know what value to look at?

Answer (score 0):

create a filter

```
myApp.filter("filterI", function() {
  return function(input, filterBy) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
       if(item.name.indexOf(filterBy) > -1) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  }
})
```

call that filter in `ng-repeat`

```
<span ng-repeat="person in people | filterI">({{person.id}}) - {{person.name}} </span>
```

this will filter the people array and repeat through filtered array.

Answer (score 0):

If you're into learning filters then this might be useful to you:

```
myApp.filter('contains', function() {
  return function(text, needle) {
    if (text) {
      if (text.indexOf(needle) != -1) {
        return text;
      } else {
        return '';
      }
    }
    return '';
  }
});
```

Include it in your html with:

```
<span ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.name| contains:'i'}} </span>
```

This way you can pass a parameter and be sure that it just filters on names.

Other answers are right too!

Nearly forgot: Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C8n6TkwvHDW2tb4EVkEJ?p=preview)